# How do I copy contents into a hash without changing the memory address to which that hash points?

Tags: ruby, hash, reference, copy

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I'm confused about the whole reference vs value thing when copying the contents of a hash.  How do I copy the contents of one hash into another without changing the reference (memory address?) of the hash?  Below is the example of the problem I'm having ....

```
2.4.0 :003 >   def copy_hash(h)
2.4.0 :004?>     new_hash = {"a" => 1}
2.4.0 :005?>     h = new_hash
2.4.0 :006?>   end
 => :copy_hash
2.4.0 :007 > h = {"b" => 2}
 => {"b"=>2}
2.4.0 :008 > copy_hash(h)
 => {"a"=>1}
2.4.0 :009 > h
 => {"b"=>2}
```

In the function, I'm assigning the parameter to a new hash ...

```
h = new_hash
```

But once the function returns the original hash is unchanged.  What's the right way to change the hash in the function so that when it returns the value of the parameter is also changed?  That is, if my hash started out as

```
 {"b" => 2}
```

I'd like the value to be

```
{"a"=>1}
```

after I invoke the "copy_hash" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Hash#replace`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-replace) to replace the contents of the hash:

```
def copy(h)
  new_hash = { 'a' => 1 }

  h.replace(new_hash)
end

h = { 'b' => 2 }
copy(h)
h == { 'a' => 1 } # => true
```